# How to make regex match all cases in a string

Tags: regex

I am testing a specific regex for input validations.

Currently, I am looking at a Map type text input, like so

`**:2;QF:30;VA:30;JQ:20;ZL:20`

Where colon separates the Key/Value and the semicolon indicates the seperation of the Key/Value pairs.

Right now I am fiddling around with a regex tester

https://regex101.com/r/4xGu8c/1

I have the regex for the key and the value, but don't know how to look through the entire string. Is there a way to look through the entire string to verify that this regex is followed? I am using Angular Valdiators.pattern to verify that a input follows this regex pattern and can only validate the first element. Would I have to use `.*?` somewhere?

Comment: Use a repetition specifier and anchor it at the beginning and end.

Comment: @Barmar Anchors  are not necessary in Angular if the pattern is defined with a string.

Comment: I don't know Angular, so I don't know how it constrains the matching.

Comment: Your regex has overlapping terms `[0-9A-Z*]{2}:(0|[1-9][0-9]*|(0|100|[1-9][0-9]?)%)` making it as useless as can be.

Comment: You should use this `(?<![^;])([^:;\s]+):([^:;\s]+)(?![^;])` https://regex101.com/r/qFgFrw/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Validators.pattern('[0-9A-Z*]{2}:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|(?:0|100|[1-9][0-9]?)%)(?:;[0-9A-Z*]{2}:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|(?:0|100|[1-9][0-9]?)%))*')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPm21I/1).

Note that Angular will automatically enclose the pattern with `^` and `$` when building the regex.

**Details**

- `[0-9A-Z*]{2}` - 2 letters, digits or asterisks
- `:` - a colon
- `(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|(?:0|100|[1-9][0-9]?)%)` - `0`, `1` to `9` followed with 0+ digits, or a percentage value
- `(?:` - start of a container non-capturing group (used to repeat a sequence of patterns):

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `[0-9A-Z*]{2}:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|(?:0|100|[1-9][0-9]?)%)` - see above
- `)*` - repeated 0 or more times